# Summing scalars and vectors [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, physics

First off; I'm not very well taught in programming, but i tend to learn exactly what I need to learn in order to do what I want when programming, I have moderate experience with python, html/css C and matlab. I've now enrolled in a physics-simulation course where I use matlab to compute the trajectory of 500 particles under the influence of 5 force-fields of different magnitude.

So now to my thing; I need to write the following for all i=1...500 particles

f_i = m*g - sum{(f_k/r_k^2)*exp((||vec(x)_i - vec(p)_k||^2)/2*r_k^2)(vec(x)_i - vec(p)_k)}

I hope its not too cluttered

And here is my code so far;

```
    clear all
    close all
    echo off
```

%Simulation Parameters-------------------------------------------

```
h = 0.01;                %Time-step h (s)
t_0 = 0;                %initial time (s)
t_f = 3;                %final time (s)
m = 1;                  %Particle mass (kg)
L = 5;                  %Charateristic length (m)
NT = t_f/h;             %Number of time steps
g = [0,-9.81]; 
f = [32 40 28 16 20];      %the force f_k (N)
r = [0.3*L 0.2*L 0.4*L 0.5*L 0.3*L];    %the radii r_k
p = [-0.2*L 0.8*L; -0.3*L -0.8*L; -0.6*L 0.1*L; 
                                          0.4*L 0.7*L; 0.8*L -0.3*L]; 
                                         %Forcefield origin position
```

%stepper = 'forward_euler';          % use forward Euler time-integration

fprintf('Simulation Parameters set');

%initialization---------------------------------------------------
    for i = 1:500              %Gives inital value to each of the 500     particles
         particle{i,1}.x = [-L -L];
         particle{i,1}.v = [5,10];
         particle{i,1}.m = m;

`for k = 1:5
             C = particle{i}.x - p(k,:);
             F = rdivide(f(1,k),r(1,k)^2).*C
             %clear C;                %Creates elements for array F
          end

      particle{i}.fi = m*g - sum(F);     %Compute attractive force on    particle
      %clear F;                         %Clear F for next use
      end`

What this code seems to do is that it goes into the first loop with index i, then goes through the 'k'-loop and exits it with a value for F then uses that last value for F(k) to compute f_i. 
What I want it to do is to put all the values of F(k) from 1-5 and put into a matrix which columns I can sum for f_i. I'd prefer to sum the columns as the first column should represent all F-components in the x-axis and the second column all F-components in the y-axis.

Note that the expression for F in the k-loop is not done.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by defining the index for F(k,:)

Comment: @Ethaan Who thanked who? Please review more carefully.

Comment: Even though this isn't detailed, it obviously answers the question, as it was posted by the OP. There is no reason to delete it.